# Header, footer and scrollable content with inner footer and full height scrollbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have a header/footer and a scrollable `div#middle`. Within the scrollable div, another (inner) footer `div#middle-bottom` should be placed at the bottom of `div#used-for-swipe-animation` and always be visible.

This is my current code using flex-container (using flex is not a requirement):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.top {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
.middle-bottom {
  background: red;
}
.bottom {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top">top</div>
      <div id="used-for-swipe-animation">
        <div class="middle">
          middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle
        </div>
        <div class="middle-bottom">
          middle-bottom<br>middle-bottom<br>middle-bottom<br>middle-bottom<br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Problem: Without the `div#used-for-swipe-animation` it works as expected. However, as the id suggests, `div#used-for-swipe-animation` is needed to perform some animation.

[image]

[image]

Nice-to-Have: Is it possible to have the scrollbar of `div#middle` to be displayed over full height of `div#wrapper`?

Answer (score 1):

As per I understand your Que, you need fixed `Header` & `Footer` and scroll `div` in middle

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main_center {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.middle-bottom {
  background: red;
}

.bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div id="used-for-swipe-animation" class="main_center">
      <div class="middle">
        middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle<br>middle
      </div>
      <div class="middle-bottom">
        middle-bottom<br>middle-bottom<br>middle-bottom<br>middle-bottom<br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">bottom</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Replay can lead perfection :)

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. 1. div#middle-bottom should always be visible and at bottom: 0 of div#used-for-swipe-animation. kind of the same behavior as div#bottom 2. Scroll bar is full height, nice, but its hidden by header and footer.

Comment: @Scholle sry but can't understand what you are looking for, a bit more explanation or demo give a proper idea.

Comment: 1. Just click in "Run code snippet" of your code. The user has to scroll down to see the red box (div#used-for-swipe-animation). I want that box to always be visible in full height (all 4 lines) without scrolling. 2. I managed it by removing overflow-y: auto; from .wrapper

Comment: Added 2 images for explanation.